# How do JS frameworks bind model to a view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've been diving into the scary stuff recently.. :) scary stuff being the source of popular `js frameworks` like `backbone.js`, `angular.js`, `vue.js` and so on.

I'll take Backbone as an example here. I am trying to figure out how is a model attached to the view?

Here is the code and if someone could just point out the part where this is happening, would be awesome!
https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js

Actually, the part I don't understand is that there is not `innerHTML` called anywhere, so how is the element being populated with the data?

Comment: First read the documentation properly... Where does it say backbone magically binds model data with view..? backbone doesn't bind the model to view. The user is free to choose how to do this for his project. Hence there is no such code in backbone source..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone is not Angular, it doesn't bind model to html for you, also it does not actually renders views for you, you have to implement render methods in your views and call them when you find appropriate. In fact, I think it might be confusing to developer coming from 2-way binding frameworks. Backbone is all about giving all the control to the developer, but you have to do all the work yourself.

Minimal model => view flow example would be something like

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

  defaults: {
    test: 'test',
  },

  initialize: function (options) {
    console.log(this.get('test'));
  },
});

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

  el: '#your-el',

  initialize: function (options) {
    this.template = _.template('<div><%= test %></div>');        
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
  },

  render: function () {
    // rendering happens here, innerHTML, $.html(), whichever you prefer
    // and you can pass model data as this.model.toJSON()
    // or you can pass an object with data
    // also, you probably will need a templating library or use 
    // bundled underscore _.template(html, data) method to render blocks of html
    // for example, with underscore 
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this; // for chaining
  },
});

var myModel = new MyModel();
var myView = new MyView({
  model: myModel,
});

myModel.set('test', 'newValue'); // view should render after this call
```

Check the list of built-in events at [backbonejs.org](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog).